# using jquery not operator

Tags: jquery

I have a setup like this.

```
        var element = $(".module-panel", this.el);
        $('.module-panel:not('+element+')').hide();
```

What I'm trying to do is hide all divs with the class .module-panel except the one that is stored inside the var element.

Comment: I'd just hide them all, and then do `element.show()` afterwards

Comment: `$('.module-panel').not(element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with .not()

```
var element = $(".module-panel", this.el);
$('.module-panel').not(element).hide();
```

**Using :not() is entirely possible** as well, and although the difference is miniscule, if there are multiple elements you're matching against, it could make a difference for the favorable CSS3 selector :not().

**jQuery creates a method** .not() which filters out any element passed to it. **CSS3 has a pseudo selector** :not() which allows the browser to do the work, making it slightly faster, but not as versatile.

Test results here: http://jsfiddle.net/iredmedia/jPNYK/

**The reason your query doesn't work** is because you are **concattenating a jQuery object into a query string**. In order to make your query work, you **must pass it a** specific element id/class **string**, as in

```
var element = '.doNotReturn',
    excluded = $('#eltFamily:not(' + element + ')').nextMethod();
```

Hope this helps you understand :not() vs .not();

Answer (score 3):

you can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
var element = $(".module-panel", this.el);
$('.module-panel').not(element).hide();
```

you will need jquery 1.4 or higher because element is a jquery object:

> .not( jQuery object )
>
> jQuery object - An existing jQuery object to match the current set of elements against.