# jquery not operator : not able to hide div

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to hide getLocation div, if clicked on someother id. 
But this doesn't work

```
$(:not("#getLocation")).click(function(){
  if($("#getLocation").show()==true){
    $("#getLocation").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: On which div/element you clicked, write that  like `$("#element_id").click(function(){});`

Comment: `$("#getLocation").toggle()`

Comment: `$(:not("#getLocation"))` What exactly you are trying to acheive?

Comment: $("#element_id").click(function(){$("#getLocation").hide();});

Comment: This not operator :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789412/using-jquery-not-operator

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('*:not("#getLocation")').click(function(){
    $("#getLocation").toggle();
});
```

syntax error only.

$('*:not("#getLocation")') => will return all element except whose id = getLocation

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

`if($("#getLocation").show()==true){`

Will never true, because it is an object.

jQuery returns an object of the element after every getter operation.

It is object chaining.

For example, if you have an element with id `myDiv`

Then you can perform three operations in a single statement like this:

```
$("#myDiv").show().css('color', 'red').css('padding', '12px 12px 12px 12px');
```

Here, after you `show()` element, an object of the element is returned.

Again you change the css and again an object is returned.

Use jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Corrected code:

```
$(':not(#getLocation)').click(function(){
  $("#getLocation").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
$("#getLocation").click(function(){

    $("#getLocation").addClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$('#getLocation').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $("#getLocation"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target` to filter out relevant div only like following :

```
<div id="a">
  Div 1
</div>
<div id="b">
  Div 2
</div>

<div id="getLocation">
 Hide/show
</div>
```

Js

```
// as example, we target all div
$('div').click(function(e){
 // but only filter div without getLocation ID
 if ( $(e.target).attr('id') != 'getLocation' ) {
   $("#getLocation").toggle();
 }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/nh912u1h/)

Answer (score 1):

You may need this.

```
$(document).not($("#getLocation")[0]).click(function(){
    if($("#getLocation").is(':visible')){
        $("#getLocation").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use container logic like normally use for navigation menu. For example if you click on outside of your div then your div goes hide.

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Hope this help you well!